# Set Color of Status and Navigation Bar in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, web, themes, navigationbar

I'm working on a Flutter app and have struggled to set the color of the navigation and status bars in my Web builds.

Currently, I'm using this method to override the theme:

```
 SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      systemNavigationBarDividerColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 250, 250, 250),
      statusBarColor: Colors.black26,
    ),
 );
```

Unfortunately, this only works for my Android build. How could I make it work for Web? I'm relatively new to FLutter, so any help would be appreciated